# Magento 2: Add custom category layout to multiple categories

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, category-view

I am trying to add a custom category layout to my theme. I have the standard `catalog_category_view.xml` and have got the update for 1 category using `catalog_category_view_id_[id].xml`.

I want to apply the update to multiple categories (around 30) without having to create multiple `catalog_category_view_id_[id].xml` for each category. Any further updates would have to be made across every file.

Is there a way to have a layout update in the design section?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Override vendor **layouts.xml** into your theme:

```
\vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\layouts.xml
```

**into**

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml
```

Add the below code into **layouts.xml** for the custom category layout.

```
<layout id="custom-category-layout">
    <label translate="true">Custom category layout</label>
</layout>
```

Create **custom-category-layout.xml** file in your theme by copy code **2columns-left.xml**:

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/page_layout/custom-category-layout.xml
```

Finally, create **catalog_category_view.xml** in your theme:
`app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Theme]/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

Update the layout name just like below:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="custom-category-layout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Now select a custom theme and category layout from admin for multiple categories.

[image]

**Note:** Due to custom layout, body class **page-layout-2columns-left** will be updated with a new one and the sidebar will not display. For that, you can add CSS by checking the two-column page layout and it will work.

**Hope it will help!**

Comment: Working fine for me..

Comment: Thanks! welcome @NavinBhudiya

Comment: When I add catalog_category_view.xml to my theme, it overrides all category pages regardless of the layout that is set in the admin settings of that category. How can I change this so that it only applies to categories that have the layout selected, and others remain with the default layout?

Answer (score 0):

I used 'Vikram Kumar' answer but this didnt fully work for me in 2023. So i wanted to add here what i did different to make it work. Credits for some steps go to him!

1. Override vendor layouts.xml into your theme:

   **\vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\layouts.xml**

into

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml
```

Add the below code into layouts.xml for the custom category layout.

```
<layout id="categorynotitle">
    <label translate="true">Category No Title</label>
</layout>
```

2. Created the following file:

   app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Theme]/Magento_Theme/page_layout/categorynotitle.xml

   ```
    <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <update handle="2columns-left"/>

    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
    </referenceContainer>


   </layout>
   ```
3. Set the new layout as a setting under the specific category.